# Issue in Xcode 7 beta 6 when using NSLocalizaedString

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, ios9, xcode7-beta6

I am having some trouble with xcode beta 7 when trying to solve a problem that apparently is crashing my app in iOS 9.0. In a first moment, i was having a problem when connecting to an unsecured http. I've followed the steps from another post here in stack overflow and got it working... Now, the problem is going through another crash right after it. I've checked apple's documentation and it says...

---

Localization

• During XLIFF export or import, NSLocalizedString macro issues or empty strings files may result in an error, "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.”

Workaround: Remove empty strings files from your project, or use the following command to find NSLocalizedString macro issues in your project.

```
find <project directory here> -name "*.m" -exec xcrun extractLocStrings {} \;
```

(21101899)

---

So i executed the command and thats whats it shows to me...

[image: Image describing the error]

I have no clue how to fix this, there is few on the internet describing the problem also... does anyone knows how to solve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find the line starting with `"Dismiss"` in your Localizable.strings file and look one line up. You will likely see two comment sections (a comment is text surrounded by `/*` and `*/`). Get rid of one of them.

Comment: i have fixed the issue but the error is still showing up in my iphone screen. Message is `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`. Now i have no clue how to fix it because i thought fixing the "Dismiss" error would just work. Is any other approach to solve it?

Comment: I've not seen this error come up on a device before. Does the `find` command you mentioned in your question report any errors?

Comment: Yes. The image represents the command and the response on the terminal. I've cleared all the errors and i am still getting the message in my device. It is a new error, since the app is on sale since iOS7.